# How can you say when a student receives "a note"?

Tags: translation, localization

In italian schools when a student misbehaves a teacher can write "a note" in his register to report his behaviour.
Is there anything like that in English? What expression do they use in English or American schools?

Comment: "misbehavior/misconduct report" ?

Comment: Does the student *necessarily* know that the record has been made? I suspect practices like this are gradually reducing over time, but perhaps what you're talking about is what in some educational/supervision environments (particularly, *schools*) might be called a [***demerit***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/demerit) *(North American) A mark awarded against someone for a fault or offence.*

Comment: A closely related term in the workplace is a "write-up".

Comment: There is no regulated way of doing this in Britain, and the system used is at the discretion of the particular school and its Head Teacher. But some appropriate record has to be maintained, for evidential purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A common expression is **mark/marked**

> 'The teacher put a mark on his permanent record'.
>
> 'He marked the register to show that the student had arrived late'.